# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Login loop upon entering the login details

Tags: drivers, nvidia, gnome, login, xorg

I am having a login loop after removing "blacklist nvidiafb" from /etc/modprobe.d/ (It was framebuffer conf file) and putting it back with sudo nano because it looked terrible.

Well, when I removed it, the graphics were very scaled high then I put back the line and rebooted but I came across the login loop.
I ran a command to see the issue and it dumped the output.
This is a sample of all the warnings received as the original file is pretty [big](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5c618j3dtfpq47e/Bootloop.txt?dl=0).

Unfortunately I can't uninstall the gnome extension without graphics and I also have a "xinit: Connection to X server lost" when I run startx.
I reinstalled nvidia-driver-390 and gnome desktop but nothing worked.
As I am not tech savvy, I noticed that something is wrong with an extension or the desktop and maybe nvidia because of the X server failure. I am almost out of ideas.

The reason of fiddling with settings was to be able to launch i386 apps via itch.io

```
 Search "WARNING" (26 hits in 1 file)
  D:\Bootloop.txt (26 hits)
    Line 103: Aug 04 13:50:55 Kazuki gnome-session[1233]: gnome-session-binary[1233]: WARNING: App 'spice-vdagent.desktop' exited with code 1
    Line 104: Aug 04 13:50:55 Kazuki gnome-session-binary[1233]: WARNING: App 'spice-vdagent.desktop' exited with code 1
    Line 117: Aug 04 13:50:56 Kazuki gnome-shell[1241]: JS WARNING: [resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/windowManager.js 1477]: reference to undefined property "MetaWindowXwayland"
    Line 349: Aug 04 13:51:04 Kazuki /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1652]:         (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
    Line 788: Aug 04 13:51:05 Kazuki /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1652]: warning: output  not found; ignoring
    Line 789: Aug 04 13:51:05 Kazuki /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1652]: warning: output  not found; ignoring
    Line 1037: Aug 04 13:51:11 Kazuki gnome-session[1706]: gnome-session-binary[1706]: WARNING: App 'spice-vdagent.desktop' exited with code 1
    Line 1038: Aug 04 13:51:11 Kazuki gnome-session-binary[1706]: WARNING: App 'spice-vdagent.desktop' exited with code 1
    Line 1065: Aug 04 13:51:13 Kazuki gnome-shell[1811]: JS WARNING: [/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com/appIcons.js 1028]: unreachable code after return statement
    Line 1089: Aug 04 13:51:35 Kazuki gnome-session[1706]: gnome-session-binary[1706]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' killed by signal 5
    Line 1093: Aug 04 13:51:35 Kazuki gnome-session-binary[1706]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' killed by signal 5
    Line 1099: Aug 04 13:51:37 Kazuki gnome-shell[3449]: JS WARNING: [/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com/appIcons.js 1028]: unreachable code after return statement
    Line 1111: Aug 04 13:51:37 Kazuki gnome-session[1706]: gnome-session-binary[1706]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' killed by signal 5
    Line 1112: Aug 04 13:51:37 Kazuki gnome-session[1706]: gnome-session-binary[1706]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' respawning too quickly
    Line 1113: Aug 04 13:51:37 Kazuki gnome-session-binary[1706]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' killed by signal 5
    Line 1116: Aug 04 13:51:37 Kazuki gnome-session-binary[1706]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' respawning too quickly
    Line 1869: Aug 04 13:53:56 Kazuki gnome-session[5948]: gnome-session-binary[5948]: WARNING: App 'spice-vdagent.desktop' exited with code 1
    Line 1870: Aug 04 13:53:56 Kazuki gnome-session-binary[5948]: WARNING: App 'spice-vdagent.desktop' exited with code 1
    Line 1925: Aug 04 13:53:56 Kazuki gnome-shell[6047]: JS WARNING: [/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com/appIcons.js 1028]: unreachable code after return statement
    Line 1961: Aug 04 13:54:16 Kazuki gnome-session[5948]: gnome-session-binary[5948]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' killed by signal 5
    Line 1962: Aug 04 13:54:16 Kazuki gnome-session-binary[5948]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' killed by signal 5
    Line 1996: Aug 04 13:54:17 Kazuki gnome-shell[6315]: JS WARNING: [/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com/appIcons.js 1028]: unreachable code after return statement
    Line 2009: Aug 04 13:54:17 Kazuki gnome-session[5948]: gnome-session-binary[5948]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' killed by signal 5
    Line 2010: Aug 04 13:54:17 Kazuki gnome-session[5948]: gnome-session-binary[5948]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' respawning too quickly
    Line 2013: Aug 04 13:54:17 Kazuki gnome-session-binary[5948]: WARNING: Application 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' killed by signal 5
    Line 2014: Aug 04 13:54:17 Kazuki gnome-session-binary[5948]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' respawning too quickly
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is pretty embarrassing. I found the solution.

About the login loop, it was about the version of the kernel I was using. Names are pretty cryptic. When I typed "sudo update-initramfs -u", I switched from 4.18.0.25 kernel to 5.0.0.23 kernel. And I have three of them listed upon booting. When I selected 4.18.0.25, there was not login loop, so the problem was in 5.0.0.23.
When I modified the framebuffer in /etc/modprobe.d, I didn't update initramfs. After updating, there was no more login loop.

Well, about the extension issue, it is because the nvidia driver was busted because I think when I upgraded the initramfs, the drivers weren't loaded and I have the GPU extension which became glitchy. I did "sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf" and added "blacklist nouveau" "blacklist lbm-nouveau" "options nouveau modeset=0" "alias nouveau off" "alias lbm-nouveau off" as a suggestion from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42984743/nvidia-smi-has-failed-because-it-couldnt-communicate-with-the-nvidia-driver) because of nvidia-smi not working.

About the Wayland issue, I uncommented it and made sure to disable it, so that Xorg would be the only option. I also deleted /etc/X11/Xorg.conf

I am happy I could fix it. It was tricky. Nvidia failure made that my resolution was set to 960x600 with no way to go higher. Not bad for the eyes but, not HD either. Also, sorry for the bother.